# MySQL - Mostrar los resultados de una tabla "A" aun cuando no haya correspondencia en tabla "B"

Tags: mysql, join, table

Tengo un problema al ejecutar una consulta sobre dos tablas MySQL.
En la tabla A tengo todos días del mes. En la tabla B tengo una serie de datos organizados por fecha, pero no hay registros en todos los días del mes.

En mi consulta, necesito ver como resultado los días que aparecen en la tabla A (todos ellos) y además los resultados de la tabla B cuando haya coincidencia de fechas con tabla A.

Ejemplo: para los 5 primeros días de octubre 2022, en la tabla A tengo:

```
DAYS  
2022-10-01
2022-10-02
2022-10-03
2022-10-04
2022-10-05
```

Ya en la tabla B, tengo los siguientes registros:

```
DATE,AMOUNT  
2022-10-02 , 12345.67  
2022-10-04 , 23468.99
```

Lo que quiero es que mi consulta me devuelva estos resultados:

```
DATE,AMOUNT
2022-10-01
2022-10-02,12345.67
2022-10-03
2022-10-04,23468.99
2022-10-05
```

El problema es que no consigo que la consulta me devuelva los registros de la tabla A cuando no hay registros en la tabla B. Solamente me devuelve resultados para los días 02 y 04 de octubre.

Después de mucho toquetear la consulta, ahora mismo la tengo así (he tenido que editar la query en esta pregunta porque la había tocado tanto que la había desvirtuado al final):

```
SELECT
TABLA_A.DATE,
SUM(TABLA_B.AMOUNT) AMOUNT
FROM TABLA_A
LEFT JOIN TABLA_B ON TABLA_A.DATE=TABLA_B.SETT_DATE
WHERE TABLA_A.DATE BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-05'
AND TABLA_B.CONDICION1='XXXX'
AND TABLA_B.CONDICION2='YYYY'
GROUP BY TABLA_A.DATE
```

Estoy bastante perdido, no entiendo de dónde viene el problema. Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda. Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Deberías ser capaz de realizar lo que necesitas con un left join explicado [en esta página](https://programacionymas.com/blog/como-funciona-inner-left-right-full-join), donde indica:

> Con **LEFT JOIN** damos prioridad a la tabla de la izquierda, y buscamos en la tabla derecha. Si no existe ninguna coincidencia para alguna de las filas de la tabla de la izquierda, de igual forma todos los resultados de la primera tabla se muestran.

De esta forma:

```
SELECT `A`.DATE, 
`B`.AMOUNT 
FROM `A` 
LEFT JOIN `B` ON `A`.DATE=`B`.DATE 
WHERE `A`.DATE IS NOT NULL 
AND `A`.DATE BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-31'
GROUP BY `A`.`DATE`;
```

Answer (score 0):

como ya te respondieron puedes usar un left join para que puedas ver lo que necesitas, aqui te dejo otra forma usando un case para no ver el resultado null que te arroja usar join, saludos

```
select
ta.fecha,
case when tb.monto>=0 then tb.monto else 0 end montos
from tabla_a ta 
left join tabla_b tb
on ta.fecha=tb.fecha
where ta.fecha between '2022-11-01' and '2022-11-05'
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, había estado toqueteando tando la query que al final había quitado el LEFT del join y no lo había vuelto a poner. En realidad no me olvidé del LEFT JOIN, fue lo primero que puse. Justo por eso vengo a pedir ayuda, yo pensaba que con esas condiciones debería recibir todos los datos de la primera tabla...